# jquery validation add rules

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm using the plugin of validation in jquery. There is a very strange thing is that, when I add rules in this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.addMethod("endDateGreaterThan", function (value, element, params) {
            if (value != "" && $(params).val() != "") {
                var endDate = formatValidateDate(value);
                var startDate = formatValidateDate($(params).val());
                if (startDate == null || endDate == null)
                    return true;
                return new Date(endDate) >= new Date(startDate);
            }
            return true;
        }, "");

var validator = $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                StartDate: "required",
                EndDate: {
                    required: true,
                    endDateGreaterThan: "#StartDate"
                },                  
                DiscountRate: {
                    required: true,
                    max: 100,
                    min: 1
                }
            },
            messages: {
                StartDate: {
                    required: "ErrorMessageStartDateRequired"
                },
                EndDate: {
                    required: "ErrorMessageEndDateRequired",
                    endDateGreaterThan: "ErrorMessageEndDateGreaterThanStartDate"
                },
                DiscountRate: {
                    required: "ErrorMessageDiscountRateRequired",
                    max: "Global.ErrorMessageDiscountRateRange",
                    min: "Global.ErrorMessageDiscountRateRange"
                }
            }
      });
```

There is no rule added. If I debug the js file and step into the validate method in jquery.validation.js file, I found that the option passed to validate method is empty.

But If I add rules dynamically, just like

```
$("#StartDate").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "StartDate is required"
            }
        });
```

The rule will be added just as what it should be.

I'm using ASP.net mvc.

Any suggestions are appreciate.

Comment: Show the rendered HTML of the `form`.  In your first case, when `rules` are defined within `.validate()`, you must use the `name` attribute as the selector.  In your second case, with the `rules('add')` method, you're targeting your field by its `id` attribute.  See the difference?  If we could see the HTML of the form, would your `rules` selectors match the fields' `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your html is wrong.  Every input that you reference in your validate code must have a `name` attribute.  So this is wrong:

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" />
```

This is right:

```
<input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
```

See the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/):

> The name attribute is '''required''' for input elements, the
>   validation plugin doesn't work without it. Usually name and id
>   attributes should have the same value.

Comment: This is true, however only a really good guess until the OP shows his rendered HTML.

Comment: True, @Sparky - seemed like the only possible answer to me, regardless of seeing the HTML... I agree the question can be improved!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example which is working fine:

```
    $("#formControl").validate({
        rules: {
            ElementTypeUid: "required",
            InternalIdentifier: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            ElementTypeUid: "Some error message",
            InternalIdentifier: "Some error message"
        }
    });
```